# Is there an efficiency measure for airports?

Tags: airport, efficiency

For large, busy airports (such as JFK), how do they measure how well they are being utilized? I assume airport management wants to serve as many flights as possible, for maximum revenue. Any time their gates are empty, or runways aren't being utilized, the airport has more capacity to sell. Is there some sort of industry standard measurement for "airport utilization efficiency"?

Answer (score 3):

The Air Transport Research Society (ATRS) has a benchmarking system for determining the efficiency of the airports.

Basically,it takes the airport size and related infrastructure (runways, no. of gates etc.) as inputs and measures the airport efficiency in terms of aircraft and passenger movement,revenue etc.

There is a yearly [Global Airport Benchmarking Report](http://www.atrsworld.org/index.html).